Upgrading phpMailer failed to run properly
After upgrading PHPMailer, my app exits just before execution these lines:
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';

...and prints the following on my screen:
IP: 76.152.50.173 at c-76-152-50-173.hsd1.ct.comcast.net
Thank you for your submission
Powered by PHPMailer-FE.php 4.11!
I need help fixing this...
Thanks in advance

PHPMailer-FE has not been supported for many years, so track down where that is coming from. Beyond that, it’s clear you’re not using composer, which doesn’t help, and we can’t do anything to help because you’ve not shown your code or file structure.
